# Possible encoding problem using PHP-7 Sockets as WebSocket Server

Tags: php, sockets, encoding, websocket, php-7

When trying to use PHP7.3 as SocketServer for WebSockets I encounter a problem where a message send from Firefox come out the socket all messed up. And always differently.

However, messages send from PHP to Firefox are fine.

For example:

```
socket.onopen = function(e)
{
    e.target.send(JSON.stringify({"sessionid" : "5e8a2f30a164e", "sockid" : "5e8a5c8cd99e6"}));
}
```

one time becomes

```
)'JR9ZT#GN.Fx+/9JL#
                            hL+J)/
                                  Z
```

next time it's

```
ZXC!+&)1,4<a`m&bj%i9rl=av+,91'xzv?9v9;'c=ux
```

Clientrequest:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.5.54:8089
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://192.168.5.54
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: uhfFVS5mhYptk6FF8jl73g==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=XDEBUG_ECLIPSE
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

Servercode[shortend]:

```
    $this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)
    $ret = socket_bind($this->socket, $this->host, $this->port);
    $ret = socket_listen( $this->socket, 0 );
    socket_set_nonblock($this->socket);
    while ($this->isServer)
    {
        $connection = @socket_accept($this->socket);
        [... forking for new connection cont in child]
    }
```

Child:

```
    socket_close($this->socket);
            [...]
    $request = socket_read($connection, 5000);  //creates above client request     
    preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n#', $request, $matches);
    $key = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($matches[1] . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    $headers = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
    $headers .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
    $headers .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
    $headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";
    //$headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: json\r\n";
    $headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $key\r\n\r\n";

    socket_write($connection, $headers, strlen($headers));
    require_once("objs/User.php");
    $user = new User();
    // Send messages into WebSocket in a loop.
    socket_set_nonblock($connection);
    while (true) 
    {

        if(($msg = socket_read($connection, 5000)) === "")
        {
            die;
        }
        if(!empty($msg))
        {
            echo $msg."\n";
        }
```

I'm at a loss here and would appreciate your help!

Comment: Hello there, I'm also working with Websocket in PHP, I have some question for you that might help me, could you explain me why you fork when there is a new connection ? Does it improve performance having child processes ? I see here that you close the master socket in the child, is it only because you handle one connection or it has to do with the fact that you forked the parent thus you need to close it in child and it stays open in the parent ? Anyway thx for you answer

Answer (score 0):

It turns out data send from client->server is always "masked" using WebSockets.

The `function unmask($payload)` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690674/encoding-unmasking-websocket-binary-data-in-php) helped me solve the problem.